# Postfix secondary transport destiny

Tags: postfix

I have a Postfix acting as a AntiSpam Gateway, as the mails are treated they are delivered to my Exchange Server using transport.
Now I want to add another postfix as a backup for the Exchange box, how can I tell the "postfix gateway" to deliver the mails to the "postfix backup" box only if Exchange is down?

THX

Answer (score 1):

You could use a local DNS server and configure two MX here.

Example:
You have your Postfix box configured as MX for **domain.com**. Internally your Exchange Server also has a domain, e.g. **exchange.domain.local**, which is configured as your transport destination in Postfix.

Now you set up two MX records for **exchange.domain.local**, one with a higher priority and one with a lower one.

This for sure assumes you have a local DNS.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so would be sending to a domain name, which would then respond with MX 10 for the primary, MX 20 for the backup, and so on. SMTP already has these sort of redundancies built in, when the primary doesn't respond, the secondary is tried.

In postfix make sure to not include the [] around the destination in transport, that way postfix will do a DNS lookup before sending.

Nick

Comment: Ben beat me to the punch :)